# Getting JAXBException intermittently for Jakarta Implementation intermittently

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting JAXBException on my app intermittently and need some help understanding why it may be occurring. It happens when I try converting an object to XML

```
private String getXml(Request request) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JAXB.marshal(request, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

When it occurs, it keeps happening for few hours, or even days sometime, and then resolves itself.
Following is the pom file dependency I have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Following is the relevant stack trace

```
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:232)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:375)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXB$Cache.<init>(JAXB.java:96)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXB.getContext(JAXB.java:123)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXB._marshal(JAXB.java:547)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:230)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.